# gitlab ci: How to share cache between fork and parent repository?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, cache

first please read the context of my inquiry.

A project named `teamspace/foo` I maintain at work makes each teammate fork it. I have a scheduled pipeline that remakes cache each night.

Now onto the problem I want to solve:

Developers want to use `teamspace/foo` cache in their forks to speed up their own pipelines.

I would like to somehow share `teamspace/foo` cache to any forked repository.

My questions therefore are :

- How to make forks use cache from parent repository?
- Is there an alternative way of working I could suggest to team members that does not involve having each fork rebuild its cache every night?